# Finder: How to make default search in folder the current folder?

Tags: mac, search, finder

When searching on using the search bar in Finder, the default search is "This Mac". I want it to be the current folder. How to change?

Comment: take a look at this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080229204517495

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was added in 10.6:

[image]

Comment: with finder being so integrated into the os, one forgets about the preference pane